# C++/CLI syntax errors (code from 2012)

Tags: c++-cli

This is C++/CLI code in a header file created in VS 2012 that we will assume worked back then.

```
namespace CLIWrapper {  
    public ref class Wrapper
    {
    public:     
        static bool call_calculator(double* liquids, double* solids, double temperature, int arraySize);        
        static void build_calculator(char** components, char* parameterSet, int arraySize);
    };
}
```

When I try to compile it now using VS 2017 I get these errors:

C2059   syntax error: 'public'

C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '{'

C2447   '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)

Any idea on what caused these or how to fix them?

Comment: My guess is that there is something above these lines that the compiler is having trouble with, though I would say that `char**` and pointers to arrays seems like a very bad idea for C++/CLI.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please give a [mcve].

Comment: Switch from the error list to the output tab. You may get more complete and descriptive error messages. In C++ there is no notion of a `public` class.  I can't speak on cli extensions though.

Comment: Just as C++ ≠ C, likewise C++/CLI ≠ C++.  Different languages.

Comment: The code I gave is all of the code in the .h file

Comment: @ConnorMote then check in the file that includes it. That error would indicate that something *before* the code shown is not considered "complete" (C2143 syntax error: missing ';' before '{')

Comment: What happen if you add 
#prama managed(push, on)
...
#pragma managed(push, off)
at the start and end of the header file?

Comment: @Mudi I get 110 new errors but those three I posted are still there.

Comment: @Mudi The top one being: C3821 'cli::interior_ptr<unsigned char>': managed type or function cannot be used in an unmanaged function

Comment: @crashmstr When I take this lib file out the code works just fine, could what your saying still be true?

Comment: Found this in the output tab: 3>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration. Not sure if it means anything but I'm wondering if I didn't set up this library correctly (it's a dll).